# Devo tomar alguma ação a respeito de usuários que não sabem usar as Tags?

Tags: debate

Hoje apareceu esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96888/sistema-em-c-com-listas-encadeadas) na fila de analise de um novo usuário, percebi que a pergunta dele estava compreensível, porem fiquei em duvida se ele precisava de ajuda com *C* ou *C++*, porque ele tinha colocado as duas Tags. Ao analisar o código dele cheguei a conclusão que era *C*, mas mesmo assim perguntei nos comentários se era realmente *C*, e caso fosse *C* para ele remover a tag *C++*, mas eu acho que minha pergunta ofendeu ele pela resposta que ele me deu nos comentários.

Não estou aqui para brigar ou prejudicar alguém, estou aqui para ajudar a comunidade e também para ser ajudado por ela.

O que eu devo fazer a respeito?

*PS: Ele removeu a tag C++.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O código funciona em C++? Então deixa a *tag*. Se alguém der uma solução exclusivamente em C++, ele não poderá reclamar e terá uma opção a mais para os demais.

O que deve ser feito quando realmente tem *tag* errada, que a falta ou sobre de uma *tag* prejudica o entendimento, classificação e localização da pergunta, é arrumar e eventualmente indicar o erro para quem precisa saber disto.

O comentário dele não parece construtivo, então sinalize para os moderadores tomarem alguma providência.

Comment: O código dele só funciona em C. Vou informar para os próximos usuários novos que estiver usando as Tags de maneira errada que prejudica o entendimento e a classificação e localização da pergunta. Obrigado pela resposta @bigown.

Comment: Você testou e não funciona em C++? Não vi nenhum motivo para não funcionar em C++.

Comment: Sim eu testei em C++ e o compilador acusou erro `getch()` nao esta declarada no escopo, eu já ia responder em C++ por isso tinha dito a ele, porem salvei o arquivo como C e rodou.

Comment: Apesar de funcionar, não deveria usar, então o código é ruim tanto para C, quanto para C++. E dá para fazer rodar em C++, mas ninguém deveria rodar isto nas duas linguagens.

Comment: Se o código roda em C++, então eu acho que não deveria ter advertido ele a respeito das Tags. O código dele esta difícil de entender, executei o programa e ele gera uma saída muito confusa a respeito do objetivo do programa que é cadastrar os Alunos e Livros.

Comment: Eu poderia até votar como muito ampla. Mas resolvi deixar, esses códigos completos que não estabelecem onde está o real problema e quem quiser ajudar vai ter que fazer debug a la carte, são problemáticos, mas dei uma chance, se não sair nada daí, é melhor fechar.

Comment: Talvez ele volte e edite a pergunta, deixando ela mais clara, mais eu não tenho certeza se ele vai voltar.